# In excel, want to only sum certain values(not as easy as SUMIF)?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have two columns on named program and one with cost values. The three programs are ABC, A, B, and C.  I want to sum the costs of all programs that contain A. All that contain B. And all that contain C.  ABC clearly is included in all the sums. The problem is that to get just these programs the spreadsheet has a filter on it which messes sumif up. Can someone help? Here is an example of what I mean:

```
program     cost
A           5.00
B           4.00
ABC         9.00
A           2.00
```

so I would want in three separate cells "sum with A"=16.00, "sum with B"=13.00, "sum with C"=9.00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Item | Total
A    | 16
B    | 13
C    | 9
```

Assuming your above range is in A1:B5, my first formula is the following Array formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND(B6,$A$1:$A$5)),0,$B$1:$B$5))}
```

You create an Array formula by entering the formula and holding down the `Ctrl+Shift` keys while you hit Enter. In my solution, I've created an area where I calculate by totals and have a column (called Item in this case) which indicates the letter I see in the original A column.

If you were trying to enter this using VBA, you would use the `FormulaArray` property:

```
Selection.FormulaArray ="SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND(B6,$A$1:$A$5)),0,$B$1:$B$5))"
```

**Update**

Restricting the calculation to only visible cells is a bit more complicated. Suppose we have your original data in cells A1:B5. Let's also suppose our test values start in cell C7 (diagonal to the source data). Our totals formula would look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($B$1:$B$5,ROW($B$1:$B$5)-ROW($B$1),0,1)), --NOT(ISERROR(FIND(C7,$A$1:$A$5))), $B$1:$B$5)
```

The following portion returns a range over the cells

```
OFFSET($B$1:$B$5,ROW($B$1:$B$5)-ROW($B$1),0,1)
```

This portion returns 1 for each visible cell and 0 for invisible cell

```
SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($B$1:$B$5,ROW($B$1:$B$5)-ROW($B$1),0,1))
```

This portion is our criteria. `NOT(ISERROR(...` will return TRUE or FALSE. The double negative sign `--` converts that value into a negative integer and then removes that negation.

```
--NOT(ISERROR(FIND(C7,$A$1:$A$5)))
```

Lastly, the `SUMPRODUCT` function multiplies the matching arrays to each other and executes the sum. The first two arrays return a series of 0's or 1's. If the row is both visible and matches our criteria, then we get 1*1 multipled by the given value in the cell. If the given cell is not visible or does not match the criteria, one of the two return a zero and it zeroes out the entire item.

Comment: This answers the question I posted perfectly thanks, unfortunately I wasn't very clear. This gets the sum for the range $A$1:$A$4 no matter what filter I have on. Is it possible to make the range dynamic and change with the visible cells?

Comment: @Kosig - That is an important aspect to the question which obviously drastically changes the answer. You should amend your post to include this requirement. I've amended my answer to accommodate.

Comment: Wow. I am very impressed. It works remarkably well. Thanks so much!

Comment: The offset was the key, I knew it would need subtotal but couldn't figure out how to have a range argument like it needs.