# How to sum of filtered rows where condition applies?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for an Excel formula which would produce the sum of all rows in a range, where a certain condition is met AND the rows are not filtered.

I know how to do each individually:

- Sum where a condition applies: `=SUMIF(A1:A10,">=0")` for all positives for instance
- Sum of all rows that are unfiltered/visible: `=SUBTOTAL(9,A1:A10)`

However, I am stumped on doing both at the same time. Is there any way to achieve this in a single formula without creating additional columns (no VBA)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In excel, want to only sum certain values(not as easy as SUMIF)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093386/in-excel-want-to-only-sum-certain-valuesnot-as-easy-as-sumif)

Comment: The question you linked to is indeed very similar, but poorly stated and tagged, which is why I hadn't found it.

Comment: and the answer similar to houdini's. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A10)-ROW(A1),0)),(A1:A10>0)+0)`

change the condition at the end as required

Answer (score 0):

You can "self join" on the source range.  Assuming a range of values, `DataRange`:

```
=SUMIFS(DataRange, DataRange, ">0", ...)
```

In this case, the source range is filtered for only positive values.